# I am trying to stop a sprite sliding after the button is no longer pressed

Tags: c#, button, position, sprite

So, I want to create a little platformer with usual things in it such as character, enemies etc. I have added a code that allows my character to move left and right, however when I stop pressing a button corresponding to the direction, the sprite keeps moving as if it was on ice. Can anyone help me fix that problem as I have not a single clue what went wrong?

```
public float speed = 2f;
Rigidbody2D mRB2D;
datasheet mDTS;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    mDTS = GetComponent<datasheet>();
    Debug.Assert(mDTS != null, "require datasheet");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    float tHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    //float tVertical = Input.Get
    mDTS.movement += (Vector2)transform.right * speed * tHorizontal * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

~

```
public float max_ms = 6f;    
public Vector2 movement = Vector2.zero;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    transform.position += (Vector3)movement * Time.deltaTime;
}

private void LateUpdate()
{
    SpeedClamp();

}

void SpeedClamp()
{
    if (movement.magnitude > max_ms)
    {
        movement = movement.normalized * max_ms;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I see.

You press the 'arrow right' button.
Now, look at this line:

```
mDTS.movement += (Vector2)transform.right * speed * tHorizontal * Time.deltaTime;
```

mDTS.movement will be increased. Let's say, it is the first time you press 'arrow right'. Let's say mDTS.movement was (0,0)-vector before pressing and now it is (1,0)-vector due to the increase.
When you release the button mDTS.movement won't be set to 0 again.

There is no 'breaking'. No friction. What you have to do is (something like this):

```
float friction = 0.95f;
float halt_speed = 0.05f;
void SpeedClamp()
{
    if (movement.magnitude > max_ms)
    {
        movement = movement.normalized * max_ms;
    }
    movement = movement * friction;
    if (movement.magnitude < halt_speed)
        movement = Vector2.Zero;
}
```

With this code the character will get slower each update. Like a car on the road when you don't accelerate anymore. Just rolling without breaking.

If you don't want any 'ice-effect' just set the movement vector to zero as soon as you release the button. Like:

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    float tHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    //float tVertical = Input.Get
    if (tHorizontal != 0.0f) {
        mDTS.movement += (Vector2)transform.right * speed * tHorizontal * Time.deltaTime;
    } else {
        mDTS.movement = Vector2.Zero;
    }
}
```

However this one would simply make your character run fast as long as you press the button, and as soon as you release the button the character will instantly stand still.